# how to render hair flat 2d style

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, normals, hair

I have found an addon (https://github.com/sentharn/encode-normals) that bakes the normals to vertex color map and that can be used in shader node editor to make hair strands appear flat basically setting each stand the value of the emitter surface normal. It does work in Eevee but it does not work in Cycles.
First question is why it doesnt work in Cycles?
Second how to make it work?
[image]